# Direct product of free groups as quotient of free product

Tags: group-theory

Let $F(X)$, $F(Y)$ be free groups, generated by (finite) sets $X$ and $Y$. Is there a good description of kernel of $f:F(X)*F(Y)\to F(X)\times F(Y)$, where $f(w_1\dots w_n)=(w_1,\dots,w_n)$ ? All I know is that kernel is normal closure of subgroup, generated by all commutators of the form $[w_X,w_Y]$, $w_X, w_Y$ are words in $F(X)$ and $F(Y)$. Is it possible to consider only commutators of generators?

Comment: The set of commutators $[a,b]$ for $a \in F(X) - \{1\}$ and $b \in F(Y) - \{1\}$ is at least a *free basis* of your kernel (This is true for any free product $A * B$ and the kernel of the canonical homomorphism $A * B \to A \times B$).

Comment: @M.U. What do you mean by "at least" in that sentence?

Comment: @DerekHolt I meant that the kernel, if generated as a subgroup only, the commutators are a free basis. But the OP asked for normally generated.

Comment: Oh I see! The kernel of $f$ is the normal closure of the set $\{ [x,y] \mid x \in X, y \in Y \}$, which is finite if $X$ and $Y$ are both finite. If each generator of $x$ commutes with each generator of $y$, then all elements of $F(X)$ commute with all elements of $F(Y)$.